# Why get env vars in php 7 is not working?

Tags: php, environment-variables, getenv

Well, I'm trying to use a env var value in PHP 7.2 something like this

```
$var1 = getenv('AWS_REGION');
[some code bla bla bla]
echo $var1;
```

but returns this

```
 Expected string, but got bool(false)
```

Even I do echo the var and nothing happens

```
echo getenv('AWS_REGION');
```

So, in console in console print the variable and returns the value

```
echo $AWS_REGION
> us-east-2
```

I have tried everything : `getenv, $_SERVER, etc.` and nothing works. I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: How are you running the script? Environment variables in your login session are not the same as in the webserver.